# alphabatical order with fixed top but absolute bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a website with alphabetical order vertically with the fixed top but the absolute bottom. here is an example site: https://www.letras.mus.br/cristiano-araujo/cifras.html

I am not good with js so can anyone please explain to me how to do it?

I have tried the scrollspy plugin but as I said I am not good with js so I am stuck

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }

    ul.nav-pills {
      top: 20px;
      position: fixed;
    }

    div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    #section1 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #1E88E5;
    }

    #section2 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #673ab7;
    }

    #section3 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ff9800;
    }

    #section41 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
    }

    #section42 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #009688;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {

      #section1,
      #section2,
      #section3,
      #section41,
      #section42 {
        margin-left: 150px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#section1">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">C</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">D <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">DE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">DF</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="section1">
          <h1>A</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section2">
          <h1>B</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section3">
          <h1>C</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section41">
          <h1>Der </h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section42">
          <h1>DF sagvsd</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It can be achieved using a CSS-only solution - position: sticky.
https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: so in the css part  ul.nav-pills {
      top: 20px;
      position: fixed;
  }  
should i use sticky instead of fixed?